# Cargo Cannot deploy to remote tomcat 8 with using cargo-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, cargo

I am trying to deploy war on tomcat8 using cargo plugin my  entry is as follows:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <container>
            <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
          </container>
          <configuration>
            <type>runtime</type>
            <properties>
              <cargo.remote.username>tomcat</cargo.remote.username>
              <cargo.remote.password>s3cret</cargo.remote.password>
              <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://localhost:1234/manager/text</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
            </properties>
          </configuration>
          <deployables>
            <deployable>
              <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
              <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
              <type>war</type>
              <properties>
                <context>/auditAPP</context>
              </properties>
            </deployable>
          </deployables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

when i trying to run this using mvn cargo:deploy its giving me the following error

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.8:deploy (default-cli) on project Audit_Management_DS: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.8:deploy failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x], type = [remote]], configuration type[runtime]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]

Comment: I am having the same trouble with cargo-maven2-plugin 1.4.16.

Answer (score 3):

Update to cargo-plugin version 1.4.13 solved this error message for me.